# My project isnt running

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i have installed eclipse a few days ago and after several problems i was able to use this programm. my first attempt if everything was working was:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

     printf("Hello, world!\n");

     return 0;

 }
```

and it works absolutely fine. so i tried to do some exercises from my professor:

[image: Code]

and there are nor errors. no warnings. eclipse is building it without any problems but nothing is happening. i showed this some friends and they are telling me the code ir correct. but why isnt eclipse doing its work then ?

sorry for my english. its not my native language :)

Comment: Please be more specific in the title.

Comment: Please show the code that is failing, not the code that works, and not a link.  We might need to code the code to try ourselves.

Comment: Please don't use images to submit code. Instead add the code using proper formatting.

Comment: Please explain what you do to execute the result of building your code. Show the commandline or describe what buttons you click.

Comment: So you built an executable.  Did you run the executable?

Comment: Did you enter `0` for `variable2`?